# In VBA how do I check if a hyperlink is sending data?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a excel document that is pulling data from many other excel files using hyperlinks. Certain clients enter their data into template files and my file pulls that data automatically through hyperlinks. For example

='http://*hyperlink*[*filename*.xlsm]Data'!E50

Now not everyone fills in all the fields therefor I am trying to write a macro that will go through the document and find either the cells that do not contain data or find the cells whose hyperlinks do not return values to be cleared and replaced with N/A.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("E47:H234")


For Each cell In rng
    If (IsEmpty(cell)) Then
        cell.Value = "N/A"
    End If

Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: It is unclear what problem you're actually having. Does your code work as required? If not then what happens; is there an error? or simply different outcomes than expected?

Comment: It does not seem to work at all when execute it nothing changes. for example wherever my document is not receiving a value from the hyperlink it just displays 0 and i want to change those 0 to N/A because I want to be able to distinguish between someone entering a 0 and not giving any data

Comment: @toupenator if you want to change your zero values then `IsEmpty()` is not going to work, because by the very nature of that function, a 0 is not a blank. Change it to be something like `If cell = 0`, but then you are assuming the data you are pulling from cannot genuinely contain a zero. Seems that you need to look at how to pull your data rather than running this afterwards.

Comment: you could just change `IsEmpty(cell)` to `if cell.value = vbnullstring`. Excellent explanation of context @TimWilkinson

Comment: ^^ that. Note that this will throw a *type mismatch* if your cell contains an error value. You can prevent that by making sure `IsError(cell.Value)` is `False` before you compare `cell.Value` to anything.

Comment: "i want to change those 0 to N/A because I want to be able to distinguish between someone entering a 0 and not giving any data" - I don't think you can reliably do this just using the existing links.  An empty source cell and one which actually contains a zero will both show up as zero (on re-reading, as @TimWilkinson already said...)  A safer approach might be to grab the link formula and then use Evaluate to run it and check whether the return value is actually zero, or just zero-length.

Comment: Ok Thank you! can you tell me how to use Evaluate works? Or how I would do that in general. Sorry I'm very new to VBA